# Как передать в параметр метода метод - Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть Скрипт_1 - SoundManager.cs, в нем содержится:

```
public IEnumerator playAudio()   {
    SoundSourceCallAnimal.Play(); // AudioSOurce
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(SoundSourceCallAnimal.clip.length);
    //Здесь должен выполняться метод из другого скрипта
}
```

Скрипт_2:

```
public void AcceptCameAnimal()      {
        StartCoroutine (SoundManager.Instance.playAudio ("Сюда я должен передать некий метод с параметром int - SwitchVoiceAnimal (randomAnimalShow)"));

    }

private void SwitchVoiceAnimal(int rand)
    {
        switch (rand) 
        {
        case 0: Debug.Log ("Tiger");    SoundManager.Instance.PlayAnimal(rand); break;
        case 1: Debug.Log ("Sheep");    SoundManager.Instance.PlayAnimal(rand); break;
        case 2: Debug.Log ("Pig");      SoundManager.Instance.PlayAnimal(rand); break;
        case 3: Debug.Log ("Monkey");   SoundManager.Instance.PlayAnimal(rand); break;
        case 4: Debug.Log ("Elephant"); SoundManager.Instance.PlayAnimal(rand); break;
        case 5: Debug.Log ("Dog");      SoundManager.Instance.PlayAnimal(rand); break;
        case 6: Debug.Log ("Cow");      SoundManager.Instance.PlayAnimal(rand); break;
        case 7: Debug.Log ("Chicken");  SoundManager.Instance.PlayAnimal(rand); break;
        case 8: Debug.Log ("Cat");      SoundManager.Instance.PlayAnimal(rand); break;
        }
    }
```

Объясните пожалуйста как такое грамотно реализовывают

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще конечно сомнительная затея хотя бы потому что метод `playAudio` одновременно и является итератором и при этом выполняет какие-то побочные действия, что само по себе выглядит странно, и на мой взгляд это довольно грязный код. Но если очень уж хочется, то в C# есть делегаты, в частности `Action`:

```
public IEnumerator playAudio(Action<int> act)   
{
    SoundSourceCallAnimal.Play(); // AudioSOurce
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(SoundSourceCallAnimal.clip.length);
    if(act != null)
        act(10); // вместо 10 можете подставить любое значение типа int
}

//...

public void AcceptCameAnimal()
{
    StartCoroutine (SoundManager.Instance.playAudio(SwitchVoiceAnimal);
}
```

Однако же на вашем месте я бы пересмотрел логику метода `playAudio`